# error: ‘deprecated’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++11, g++

I updated my program to --std=c++11 and now I get:

```
g++ --std=c++11 -c eqc.cpp
In file included from eqc.cpp:16:0:
eqc.h:372:80: error: ‘deprecated’ was not declared in this scope
eqc.h:372:92: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
eqc.h:372:92: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
In file included from eqc.cpp:16:0:
eqc.h:372:74: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
 equation &operator[](const std::string &label) __attribute__((deprecated));
```

If I use the new way of specifying attributes, it's the same:

```
In file included from eqc.cpp:16:0:
eqc.h:371:67: error: ‘deprecated’ was not declared in this scope
eqc.h:371:79: error: expected ‘]’ before ‘;’ token
In file included from eqc.cpp:16:0:
eqc.h:371:61: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘]’ token
   equation &operator[](const std::string &label) [[deprecated]];
```

Since I can't find anything on the web about this error, I must be making some silly mistake. But which?

The system is Ubuntu 16.04 and the compiler: 
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: Try std=gnu++11

Comment: [mcve] please. The problem is [not reproducible](http://ideone.com/hpy0N9).

Comment: Right. The minimal example helped me to find the problem. In a GiNaC include file (compiler.h) it says: `#define deprecated __attribute__ ((deprecated));' and obviously this breaks all future uses of deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a library (libginac6 1.7.0) that said

```
#define deprecated attribute ((deprecated));
```

After updating the library (to version >= 1.7.1) the error disappeared since the library now says

```
#define attribute_deprecated attribute ((deprecated));
```